# spacy installation error (running cythonize failed)

Tags: python, cython, spacy

So I was compiling spacy from source. I have cython v23.4 installed. when I run `pip install -e .` in the `spaCy` directory, I get this:
`Obtaining file:///home/nitish/spaCy
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cymem.cymem cimport Pool
from thinc.typedefs cimport weight_t
^
------------------------------------------------------------

syntax/transition_system.pxd:2:0: 'thinc/typedefs.pxd' not found
Processing gold.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nitish/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 156, in <module>
    run(args.root)
  File "/home/nitish/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 147, in run
    process(base, filename, db)
  File "/home/nitish/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 113, in process
    preserve_cwd(base, process_pyx, root + '.pyx', root + '.cpp')
  File "/home/nitish/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 78, in preserve_cwd
    func(*args)
  File "/home/nitish/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 60, in process_pyx
    raise Exception('Cython failed')
Exception: Cython failed
Cythonizing sources
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nitish/spaCy/setup.py", line 265, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/home/nitish/spaCy/setup.py", line 216, in setup_package
    generate_cython(root, 'spacy')
  File "/home/nitish/spaCy/setup.py", line 148, in generate_cython
    raise RuntimeError('Running cythonize failed')
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed
```

`

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

As you install from the local repository, you should install the requirements first.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

from the spaCy repository.

Do you have a specific reason for using the `-e` option? If not, I recommend to use `--user` instead.